# How can I acquire free two-player D&D Basic/Expert adventures?

Tags: new-players, published-adventures, dnd-bx, one-on-one

My girlfriend and I have the Dungeons & Dragons Basic Rules Set 1, Expert Rule Book, and Game Adventure Book. We're looking for free two-player adventures which we could run by ourselves. We'd like them to be simple and straight-forward, as we are beginners. How can I go about finding this kind of adventure?

Comment: I'm going to let this reopen but everyone keep in mind the site rules.  Answers should be about how to find beginner adventures for B/X D&D. Not providing specific adventures or recommending other games.

Answer (score 7):

Go to [Drivethrurpg](http://www.drivethrustuff.com) and select the rules system "D&D" and the subsystem "Basic/BECMI" then sort by price ([resulting page](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_44828_0_0&page=1&sort=3a)).  This includes several free beginner adventures for B/X D&D but you'll have to search the list to find the ones that meet your needs.

There is also a [shared spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0Ar9Wm_5gI_1TdGlyZHpwRHFoU2pEMng0NkhqTlJEYmc&type=view&f=true&sortcolid=0&sortasc=false&rowsperpage=1000) of products released in the OSR (a loosely affiliated set of people who enjoy older RPGs, especially older D&D).  This has a type column you can sort or filter to get only adventures.  It also includes costs so you can filter for free materials.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend that you take a look at [Black Streams: Solo Heroes](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/114895/Black-Streams-Solo-Heroes).  This is a free supplement from Sine Nomine which provides rules allowing you to run a single player character through pretty much any published D&D adventure without requiring modification.  This would allow you to look for beginner adventures in general without needing to specifically look for adventures intended to be played one-on-one.

Solo Heroes was originally written for Labyrinth Lord, which is a B/X retroclone, so it should work perfectly with "real" B/X.  (I have used Solo Heroes' systems in play, and they work very well, but I haven't personally used them with genuine TSR B/X.)

The primary mechanic of Solo Heroes is based around remapping the damage mechanic so that PCs take hit *points* of damage, while monsters take hit *dice* of damage, so it also works well with any version of D&D or D&D-like systems which use HP and HD, not just B/X-based rule sets.

Another option which would allow for solo play of standard modules would be to load up on henchmen.  Which option would be better in your case depends on whether you prefer to have a single heroic PC operating mostly-alone (Solo Heroes) or a PC who is a leader, bringing a more traditional party of adventurers into the adventure under their command (henchmen).

Comment: Seems like this is part 1 of an answer that also tells him how to go find free simple B/X adventures to adapt. As it stands, it is not a valid answer to the question posed. Please take further debate of that to Meta.